# if statements to choose correct MySQL SELECT based on user input

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I am trying to build a table display MySQL data based off user input. The user selects various criteria by way of checkboxes and radio's. The values of each selected items is successfully sent to my php page via ajax (tested successfully). I then have 6 different select statements that can be run depending on the user input. Each statement works perfectly when tested individually. However, I tried to set up a series of if statements to select the correct statement. My problem is that no matter what criteria is selected, it always displays the first select statement.

Also, I feel the my current code is highly inefficient and I am unsure if its currently vulnerable to SQL Injection?

PHP CODE:

Get ajax results:

```
//Get date range.

$revenuefromajax=$_POST['revenuefrom'];
$revenuetoajax=$_POST['revenueto'];

$revenuefromstring = strtotime($revenuefromajax);
$revenuetostring = strtotime($revenuetoajax);

$revenuefrom=date("Y-m-d", $revenuefromstring);
$revenueto=date("Y-m-d", $revenuetostring);

//Get selected Status Values.

if (isset($_POST['revenue_checkboxes'])) {
  $revenue_check = $_POST['revenue_checkboxes'];
};

if (isset($_POST['revenueTblType'])) {
  $revenueTblType = $_POST['revenueTblType'];
  print_r($revenueTblType);
};

if (isset($_POST['revenueWO'])) {
  $revenueWO = $_POST['revenueWO'];
  print_r($revenueWO);
};

if (isset($_POST['revenueWODate'])) {
  $revenueWODate = $_POST['revenueWODate'];
  print_r($revenueWODate);
};
```

If statements:

```
//*************Customer Table Type************//

if ($revenueTblType == 'Customer') {

    //SELECT statement pulls ALL COMPLETED history info by CUSTOMER.
    $sql1 = "SELECT x.company, x.revenue, x.stagestatus, x.shippeddate, FORMAT(SUM(x.totprice), 2) as totalprice, FORMAT(SUM(x.sgtotquantity), 2) as totqty, FORMAT(SUM(x.sgtotalsqft), 2) as sgtotsqft, FORMAT(SUM(x.totprice)/SUM(x.sgtotalsqft), 2) as avgsqftrevenue, FORMAT(SUM(x.totprice)/SUM(x.sgtotquantity), 2) as avgunitrevenue FROM (SELECT t1.company, t1.revenue, t1.stagestatus, t1.shippeddate, t1.id, TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM t1.totalprice) AS totprice, t2.invoiceid, SUM(t2.quantity) AS sgtotquantity, SUM(t2.width * t2.height * t2.quantity ) /144 AS sgtotalsqft, (TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM t1.totalprice)/(SUM(t2.width * t2.height * t2.quantity ) /144)) as avgsqftrev, (TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM t1.totalprice) / SUM(t2.quantity)) AS avgunitrev
      FROM invoices AS t1 INNER JOIN lineitems AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.invoiceid
      WHERE (t2.invoiceid = t1.id)
      GROUP BY t1.id) x
      WHERE x.stagestatus='Complete'
      GROUP BY x.company ASC";



    //SELECT statement pulls DATE RANGE COMPLETED history info by CUSTOMER.
    $sql2 = "SELECT x.company, x.revenue, x.stagestatus, x.shippeddate, FORMAT(SUM(x.totprice), 2) as totalprice, FORMAT(SUM(x.sgtotquantity), 2) as totqty, FORMAT(SUM(x.sgtotalsqft), 2) as sgtotsqft, FORMAT(SUM(x.totprice)/SUM(x.sgtotalsqft), 2) as avgsqftrevenue, FORMAT(SUM(x.totprice)/SUM(x.sgtotquantity), 2) as avgunitrevenue FROM (SELECT t1.company, t1.revenue, t1.stagestatus, t1.shippeddate, t1.id, TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM t1.totalprice) AS totprice, t2.invoiceid, SUM(t2.quantity) AS sgtotquantity, SUM(t2.width * t2.height * t2.quantity ) /144 AS sgtotalsqft, (TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM t1.totalprice)/(SUM(t2.width * t2.height * t2.quantity ) /144)) as avgsqftrev, (TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM t1.totalprice) / SUM(t2.quantity)) AS avgunitrev
      FROM invoices AS t1 INNER JOIN lineitems AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.invoiceid
      WHERE (t2.invoiceid = t1.id)
      GROUP BY t1.id) x
      WHERE x.stagestatus='Complete' AND x.shippeddate BETWEEN '".$revenuefrom."' AND '".$revenueto."'
      GROUP BY x.company ASC";



    //SELECT statement pulls ALL STATUS history info by CUSTOMER.
     $sql3 = "SELECT x.company, x.revenue, x.stagestatus, x.shippeddate, FORMAT(SUM(x.totprice), 2) as totalprice, FORMAT(SUM(x.sgtotquantity), 2) as totqty, FORMAT(SUM(x.sgtotalsqft), 2) as sgtotsqft, FORMAT(SUM(x.totprice)/SUM(x.sgtotalsqft), 2) as avgsqftrevenue, FORMAT(SUM(x.totprice)/SUM(x.sgtotquantity), 2) as avgunitrevenue FROM (SELECT t1.company, t1.revenue, t1.stagestatus, t1.shippeddate, t1.id, TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM t1.totalprice) AS totprice, t2.invoiceid, SUM(t2.quantity) AS sgtotquantity, SUM(t2.width * t2.height * t2.quantity ) /144 AS sgtotalsqft, (TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM t1.totalprice)/(SUM(t2.width * t2.height * t2.quantity ) /144)) as avgsqftrev, (TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM t1.totalprice) / SUM(t2.quantity)) AS avgunitrev
      FROM invoices AS t1 INNER JOIN lineitems AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.invoiceid
      WHERE (t2.invoiceid = t1.id)
      GROUP BY t1.id) x
      WHERE x.stagestatus IN (". implode(',', array_map(function($item) {return '"' . $item . '"'; }, $revenue_check)) .")
      GROUP BY x.company ASC";




    echo "<table id='revenueReportA' align='center' class='report_DT'>
    <thead>
    <tr>

    <th>Customer</th>
    <th>Total Revenue</th>
    <th>Total SQ FT</th>
    <th>AVG Revenue Per SQ FT</th>
    <th>Total Number of Units</th>
    <th>AVG Revenue Per Unit</th>
    </tr>
    </head>";


  if (($revenueWO == 'Completed Workorders') and ($revenueWODate == 'All Workorders')) {
     $result = $conn->query($sql1);

     if ($result = $conn->query($sql1)) {

        // fetch associative array 
         while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            echo "<tbody>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['company'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" ."$". $row['totalprice'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['sgtotsqft'] ."&nbsp;&nbsp;". "ft<sup>2</sup>". "</td>";
            echo "<td>" ."$". $row['avgsqftrevenue'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['totqty'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" ."$". $row['avgunitrevenue'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</tbody>";
            }//End table while. 
            echo "</table>";
            echo "<BR>";
     }//End table if.

     //Free the result variable. 
     $result->free();

  }//End table build if.


  else if (($revenueWO == 'Completed Workorders') and ($revenueWODate == 'Workorder Date Range')) {
     $result = $conn->query($sql2);

     //Display daterange and table.
     echo 'Displaying results for: '.$revenuefrom.' to '.$revenueto.'. '.'<BR><BR>';

      if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {

        // fetch associative array 
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

          echo "<tbody>";
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['company'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" ."$". $row['totalprice'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['sgtotsqft'] ."&nbsp;&nbsp;". "ft<sup>2</sup>". "</td>";
          echo "<td>" ."$". $row['avgsqftrevenue'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['totqty'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" ."$". $row['avgunitrevenue'] . "</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
          echo "</tbody>";
          }//End table while.
          echo "</table>";
          echo "<BR>";
     }//End table if.

     //Free the result variable. 
     $result->free();

  }//End table build if.


  else if ($revenueWO == 'Workorder Status') {
     $result = $conn->query($sql3);

     if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {

        // fetch associative array 
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

          echo "<tbody>";
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['company'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" ."$". $row['totalprice'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['sgtotsqft'] ."&nbsp;&nbsp;". "ft<sup>2</sup>". "</td>";
          echo "<td>" ."$". $row['avgsqftrevenue'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['totqty'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" ."$". $row['avgunitrevenue'] . "</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
          echo "</tbody>";
          }//End table while. 
          echo "</table>";
          echo "<BR>";
    }//End table if.

    //Free the result variable. 
    $result->free();

  }//End table build if.


}//End Customer Table if statement.


//*************Revenue Category Table Type************//

else if ($revenueTblType == 'Revenue Category') {


    //SELECT statement pulls ALL COMPLETED history info by REVENUE.
    $sql4 = "SELECT x.company, x.revenue, x.stagestatus, x.shippeddate, FORMAT(SUM(x.totprice), 2) as totalprice, FORMAT(SUM(x.sgtotquantity), 2) as totqty, FORMAT(SUM(x.sgtotalsqft), 2) as sgtotsqft, FORMAT(SUM(x.totprice)/SUM(x.sgtotalsqft), 2) as avgsqftrevenue, FORMAT(SUM(x.totprice)/SUM(x.sgtotquantity), 2) as avgunitrevenue FROM (SELECT t1.company, t1.revenue, t1.stagestatus, t1.shippeddate, t1.id, TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM t1.totalprice) AS totprice, t2.invoiceid, SUM(t2.quantity) AS sgtotquantity, SUM(t2.width * t2.height * t2.quantity ) /144 AS sgtotalsqft, (TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM t1.totalprice)/(SUM(t2.width * t2.height * t2.quantity ) /144)) as avgsqftrev, (TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM t1.totalprice) / SUM(t2.quantity)) AS avgunitrev
      FROM invoices AS t1 INNER JOIN lineitems AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.invoiceid
      WHERE (t2.invoiceid = t1.id)
      GROUP BY t1.id) x
      WHERE x.stagestatus='Complete'
      GROUP BY x.revenue ASC";



    //SELECT statement pulls DATE RANGE COMPLETED history info by REVENUE.
    $sql5 = "SELECT x.company, x.revenue, x.stagestatus, x.shippeddate, FORMAT(SUM(x.totprice), 2) as totalprice, FORMAT(SUM(x.sgtotquantity), 2) as totqty, FORMAT(SUM(x.sgtotalsqft), 2) as sgtotsqft, FORMAT(SUM(x.totprice)/SUM(x.sgtotalsqft), 2) as avgsqftrevenue, FORMAT(SUM(x.totprice)/SUM(x.sgtotquantity), 2) as avgunitrevenue FROM (SELECT t1.company, t1.revenue, t1.stagestatus, t1.shippeddate, t1.id, TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM t1.totalprice) AS totprice, t2.invoiceid, SUM(t2.quantity) AS sgtotquantity, SUM(t2.width * t2.height * t2.quantity ) /144 AS sgtotalsqft, (TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM t1.totalprice)/(SUM(t2.width * t2.height * t2.quantity ) /144)) as avgsqftrev, (TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM t1.totalprice) / SUM(t2.quantity)) AS avgunitrev
      FROM invoices AS t1 INNER JOIN lineitems AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.invoiceid
      WHERE (t2.invoiceid = t1.id)
      GROUP BY t1.id) x
      WHERE x.stagestatus='Complete' AND x.shippeddate BETWEEN '".$revenuefrom."' AND '".$revenueto."'
      GROUP BY x.revenue ASC";



    //SELECT statement pulls ALL STATUS history info by REVENUE.
    $sql6 = "SELECT x.company, x.revenue, x.stagestatus, x.shippeddate, FORMAT(SUM(x.totprice), 2) as totalprice, FORMAT(SUM(x.sgtotquantity), 2) as totqty, FORMAT(SUM(x.sgtotalsqft), 2) as sgtotsqft, FORMAT(SUM(x.totprice)/SUM(x.sgtotalsqft), 2) as avgsqftrevenue, FORMAT(SUM(x.totprice)/SUM(x.sgtotquantity), 2) as avgunitrevenue FROM (SELECT t1.company, t1.revenue, t1.stagestatus, t1.shippeddate, t1.id, TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM t1.totalprice) AS totprice, t2.invoiceid, SUM(t2.quantity) AS sgtotquantity, SUM(t2.width * t2.height * t2.quantity ) /144 AS sgtotalsqft, (TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM t1.totalprice)/(SUM(t2.width * t2.height * t2.quantity ) /144)) as avgsqftrev, (TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM t1.totalprice) / SUM(t2.quantity)) AS avgunitrev
      FROM invoices AS t1 INNER JOIN lineitems AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.invoiceid
      WHERE (t2.invoiceid = t1.id)
      GROUP BY t1.id) x
      WHERE x.stagestatus IN (". implode(',', array_map(function($item) {return '"' . $item . '"'; }, $revenue_check)) .")
      GROUP BY x.revenue ASC";




    echo "<table id='revenueReportA' align='center' class='report_DT'>
    <thead>
    <tr>

    <th>Revenue Category</th>
    <th>Total Revenue</th>
    <th>Total SQ FT</th>
    <th>AVG Revenue Per SQ FT</th>
    <th>Total Number of Units</th>
    <th>AVG Revenue Per Unit</th>
    </tr>
    </head>";



    if (($revenueWO == 'Completed Workorders') and ($revenueWODate == 'All Workorders')) {
        $result = $conn->query($sql4);

         if ($result = $conn->query($sql4)) {

            // fetch associative array 
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

              echo "<tbody>";
              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['revenue'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" ."$". $row['totalprice'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['sgtotsqft'] ."&nbsp;&nbsp;". "ft<sup>2</sup>". "</td>";
              echo "<td>" ."$". $row['avgsqftrevenue'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['totqty'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" ."$". $row['avgunitrevenue'] . "</td>";
              echo "</tr>";
              echo "</tbody>";
              }//End table while.
              echo "</table>";
              echo "<BR>";

         }//End table if.

         //Free the result variable. 
         $result->free();

    }//End table build if.

    else if (($revenueWO == 'Completed Workorders') and ($revenueWODate == 'Workorder Date Range')) {
        $result = $conn->query($sql5);

        //Display daterange and table.
        echo 'Displaying results for: '.$revenuefrom.' to '.$revenueto.'. '.'<BR><BR>';

        if ($result = $conn->query($sql5)) {

            // fetch associative array 
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

              echo "<tbody>";
              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['revenue'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" ."$". $row['totalprice'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['sgtotsqft'] ."&nbsp;&nbsp;". "ft<sup>2</sup>". "</td>";
              echo "<td>" ."$". $row['avgsqftrevenue'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['totqty'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" ."$". $row['avgunitrevenue'] . "</td>";
              echo "</tr>";
              echo "</tbody>";
              }//End table while.
              echo "</table>";
              echo "<BR>";

         }//End table if.

         //Free the result variable. 
         $result->free();

    }//End table build if.

    else if ($revenueWO == 'Workorder Status') {
        $result = $conn->query($sql6);

        if ($result = $conn->query($sql6)) {

            // fetch associative array 
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

              echo "<tbody>";
              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['revenue'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" ."$". $row['totalprice'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['sgtotsqft'] ."&nbsp;&nbsp;". "ft<sup>2</sup>". "</td>";
              echo "<td>" ."$". $row['avgsqftrevenue'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['totqty'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" ."$". $row['avgunitrevenue'] . "</td>";
              echo "</tr>";
              echo "</tbody>";
              }//End table while.
              echo "</table>";
              echo "<BR>";

         }//End table if.

         //Free the result variable. 
         $result->free();

    }//End table build if.


}//End Revenue Category Table Type if.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//Close the Database connection.
$conn->close();
```

At the very least, suggestions to get this code working will be greatly appreciated. Best outcome would be improved efficiency and safety.

Thank you!!

NOTE: @Strawberry. This question is not a duplicate to the link posted because this question seeks advice regarding if statements. That link is a question regarding the MySQL Select statement itself.

Comment: `if ($revenueTblType = 'Customer') {` ?? or `if ($revenueTblType == 'Customer') {`

Comment: `devpro = devpro` , means assigning. AND `devpro == devpro` in this case you are checking either devpro equal or not.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Devpro's right.  Also, the `=` operator will return a "truthy" value, so the `if` blocks will execute regardless of the initial value of the variables you're checking.

Comment: For information about how to safeguard your system against SQL injection, refer to [bobby-tables.com](http://bobby-tables.com).  They have sample code for a variety of popular languages.  It's not difficult to incorporate these practices in your own projects.

Comment: 1. I need caffeine. Can't believe I missed that... 2) Now, my code can't display any tables... Just the table headers...

Comment: * sry table headers DON'T display either